# Port mirroring on multiple switches

Tags: cisco, monitoring

So here is the deal, I have a server on switch A where port 3 is monitoring traffic for most of the ports on switch A. However I have other users on switch B that needs to have port 3 on switch A monitor as well. Is this possible? I have been reading about rspan but doesnt seem to work.

Switch A:

```
monitor session 1 source interface fast0/1 - 2
monitor session 1 source interface fast0/4 - 46
monitor session 1 destination interface fast0/3
```

(this works great for switch A, I need a solution to get switch B to also have some ports sent to port 3 on switch A for monitoring.)

Onxx,

All the traffic on switch A is fine, there will be about 10-15 ports on switch B that I need to send to fa0/3 on switch A as the destination. I have the switches connected with a ethernet cable with a trunk port on both switches on port 48 on switch B and A and port 47 on A connects to our sonicwall. So I am assuming they are daisy chained?

What if I did the following:

Switch A
monitor session 1 source interface fast0/1 - 2
monitor session 1 source interface fast0/4 - 46
monitor session 1 destination interface fast0/3
Put all of the ports on vlan 10 because I made an rspan vlan 10

On switch B

monitor the ports I need will say 1-10

monitor session 1 source interface fast0/1 - 10
monitor session 1 destination remote vlan 10
as a prerequisite I would have created vlan 10 as a rspan vlan on switch B.

Switch A

Monitor session 1 destination remote vlan 10

Would this work?

By the way I am working with cisco catalyst 3560 switches.

Comment: Hi Matt, just a few quick questions. Are you wanting all traffic sent to the user on switch B? how are your switches configured? Are they stacked on daisy chained or Vlan routed? Please update your question.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for updating the question and sorry for the late response.

Try this configuration instead. Just make sure the VLan ID match up and are pingable to from both switches.

======Taken from [Cisco.com Rspan](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/switches/ps708/products_tech_note09186a008015c612.shtml#topic5)=====

local switch.

c3750(config)#monitor session 1 source vlan < Remote RSPAN VLAN ID >
c3750(config)#monitor session 1 source vlan 5
c3750(config)#monitor session 1 destination interface fastethernet 0/3

On the remote switch, use this configuration:

c3750_remote(config)#monitor session 1 source vlan 7
c3750_remote(config)#monitor session 1 destination remote vlan  
===== End of line ======

Hope this helps.

Check this out [Cisco CCNA](http://www.cisco.com/web/CA/learning/le3/le2/le0/le9/learning_certification_type_home.html) this will bring you up to speed on the basics as a junior.

Hi Matt, Here is some extra information you should look into; these links will in understanding of how Vlans work and how to make them work together. They are both good sources of information and should be easy to follow. You dont need to use VTP for you current environment.

Additonal reading materials:

[Cisco press Vlans](http://www.ciscopress.com/articles/article.asp?p=29803)
[Creating Ethernet VLANs on Catalyst Switches](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk389/tk689/technologies_configuration_example09186a008009478e.shtml)

Cheers,
Onxx

Comment: do I need to put all the other monitored ports on vlan 10 as well?
example:
interface range fastethernet0/4 - 45 ???

Comment: Also I see you are using vlan 5 on the local switch and 7 on the remote switch, the rspan vlan on my switches are 10 does it matter?

Comment: no on the local switch you can specific which ints you want plus specify a VLan. It doesn't matter that is just an example. You can specify multiple different source traffic i.e. ints and vlans. It might be easier to put everything you want to monitor into one or 2 vlans. I would do a simple test with the remote vlan first to make sure you are getting the right traffic.

Comment: I tried the commands you suggested and not my monitor port is not receiving any traffic. i did the followg:
local switch:
monitor session 1 source vlan 10
monitor session 1 destination interface fastethernet 0/3

Remote switch:
monitor session 1 source vlan 10
monitor session 1 destination remote vlan 10

Comment: Keep in mind I had removed my command i had in there previously before your suggestion:
Switch A
monitor session 1 source interface fast0/1 - 2
monitor session 1 source interface fast0/4 - 46

Comment: Is vlan 10 pingable from switch A?

Comment: and what IOS version are you running is it RSpan compatible?

Comment: I dont have any ports on vlan 10 to even ping. SHould the monitor port and other interfaces be on that vlan?

Comment: http://i49.tinypic.com/14dg6y0.png
I added port 3

Comment: 3560 running 12.2(35)SE5 (IPBASE)

Comment: yes, if all devices are on the same subnet, then the vlans must be the same. So you will need one port on your switch that has the vlan 10. is they are on different subnets then there must be a port on that subnet for communications for switch one.

Comment: Hi Matt, please see my updated answer. Without seeing all your configs I don't know what configuration you are missing for the vlans and if they can communicate. I would start with getting switch A and B interfaces being able to talk. As you are using the native vlan 1 it might make more sense for you you just to move your monitor port to its own vlan x and have everything else on vlan 1 for switch A and B.

Comment: Onxx,
I will be sure to do that. In the mean time what command can I use to pull for you to see? Right now I have everything back on vlan1 default. I can put the monitoring port on vlan 10 (rspan vlan) if that is recommended.